# Can we enable deleting/modifying incoming emails?

Tags: activities

the activities of type incoming emails seems to be hardcoded to not have the edit or delete button, even for admin.

Some of my users need to be able to delete it (eg. if it's a spam email) or edit it (if it's mangled somehow). Is there an option?

Would it make sense to write an extension to allow it? It isn't an issue of permission, as if you alter the url, you can still delete them

X+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. I think the original reasons behind not including it were some combination of:

a. It was for the CiviCase folks, where we did not want to delete anything

b. It was used internally, so spam was not an issue